# Tap to jump problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

**Problem**

So I've released this game called Jumpol on the iOS and Android app stores and it works fine. The only problem is that the jumping mechanic is a bit funky. Sometimes when I and other players tap, my player sometimes jumps and other times doesn't jump. Also when you tap the screen near the sides, it sometimes doesn't jump. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Link to Game (If you want to see for yourself)**

[Android Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SiddharthN.TheLongRush)

[iOS Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jumpol/id1331808162?ls=1&mt=8)

**C# Code**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody rb;

    float speed = 640;              // Speed of player.
    float thrust = 40;              // Jump force.
    float gravity = -6.18f;         // Gravity force.

    bool isGrounded = false;        // If on ground or not.

    private void Start () {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

    }

    private void Update () {

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor) DesktopControls ();

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) MobileControls ();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate () {

        if (GameManager.Instance.started) {

            Move ();
            Gravity ();

        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = true;
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionExit (Collision collision) {

        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = false;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Controls for mobile devices.
    /// </summary>
    private void MobileControls () {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) Jump ();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Controls for desktops.
    /// </summary>
    private void DesktopControls () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) Jump ();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Makes player jump.
    /// </summary>
    private void Jump () {

        if (instructions.activeSelf) {
            instructions.SetActive (false);
        }

        if (isGrounded) {
            rb.velocity += new Vector3 (0, thrust, 0);

            SoundManager.Instance.PlayOneShot (SoundManager.Instance.jump);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds gravity.
    /// </summary>
    private void Gravity () {

        rb.velocity += new Vector3 (0, gravity, 0);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves player.
    /// </summary>
    private void Move () {

        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your isGrounded variable. I would recommend you write a Debug.Log inside of touch or maybe inside update just to check if the variable is set back to true as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes when I and other players tap, my player sometimes jumps and other times doesn't jump.

Your code relies heavily on collision events to implement your `isGrounded` state. Which don't get me wrong, the Unity Physics system is a powerful and capable system, however, in the Unity physics engine, Rigidbody objects and collisions simulated at runtime can give imperfect results at times. It's more of an approximation in practice so these approximations aren't always exact.

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) {

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

}

private void OnCollisionExit (Collision collision) {

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        isGrounded = false;
    }

}
```

I would suggest not having your `isGrounded` state changes in `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit`, but instead, do a short Raycast check. Your player rigidbody object can easily move from `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` causing your `isGround` bool to move from `true` to `false` when moving along the `ground` tagged object when you expect it to consistently be grounded, causing your `jump` calls to be ignored thinking you are in airborne. I would suggest to **implement a more reliable ground checking system.**

For an example of how you could implement a [Raycast based platformer system here is an example from Unity themselves with video and code in the link and all:](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/creating-basic-platformer-game)

```
void Update () 
{
    grounded = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && grounded)
    {
        jump = true;
    }
}
```

It was originally meant for 2D so there are Physics2D function calls, however, the logic would be the same and you would need to swap out the 2D calls to their 3D equivalent. (ex. `Physics.Raycast` instead of `Physics2D.Linecast`)

> Also when you tap the screen near the sides, it sometimes doesn't jump.

As for this, I would say its related to the problem I addressed above. Looking at the screenshots on your iOS App product page, I didn't see any UI on the sides there that might be in the way that could specifically block touch input events.

Comment: Very detailed answer! Welcome to [so]!

Comment: Thank you! Long time lurker, time to give back!